# Android JSON org.json.JSONEXCEPTION: No Value for ""

Tags: android, json

I am trying to use Android get the SpeedLimit value from a JSON server response (HERE API - http://route.st.nlp.nokia.com/routing/6.2/getlinkinfo.json?waypoint=52.5308,13.3846&app_id=your_app_id&app_code=your_app_code):

`{
  "Response": {
    "MetaInfo": {
      "MapVersion": "2015Q1",
      "ModuleVersion": "0.2",
      "InterfaceVersion": "4.2",
      "Timestamp": "2015-08-25T16:15:23.540Z"
    },
    "Link": [
      {
        "_type": "PrivateTransportLinkType",
        "LinkId": "-931447246",
        "Shape": [
          "52.5309486,13.38447",
          "52.5306702,13.38344",
          "52.5305786,13.38307"
        ],
        "SpeedLimit": 13.89,
        "DynamicSpeedInfo": {
          "TrafficSpeed": 8.89,
          "TrafficTime": 11.6,
          "BaseSpeed": 13.89,
          "BaseTime": 7.4
        },
        "Address": {
          "Label": "Invalidenstraße",
          "Country": "DE",
          "State": "Berlin",
          "County": "Berlin",
          "City": "Berlin",
          "District": "Mitte",
          "Street": "Invalidenstraße"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}`

Here is the code I'm using the get the result out of the JSON:

```
try {
        JSONObject response = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
        JSONObject test = response.getJSONObject("Link");
        String test1 = test.getString("SpeedLimit");

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), test1,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error" + e.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

I keep getting the following exception:

```
org.json.JSONEXCEPTION: No Value for Link
```

I must be asking for the wrong information within the JSON but I can't seem to work this one out.

Thank you everyone!

Comment: there is no JSONObject called `Link` in your document.

Comment: I can't seem to get any information out of the JSON. No matter what I put I get the same error. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

`Link` JSONArray is inside `Response` JSONObject instead of in root JSONObject.

So, first need to get `Response` JSONObject from  `response` then get `Link` JSONArray:

```
// Response JSONObject
JSONObject responseJSONObject = response.getJSONObject("Response");
// get Link JSONArray from responseJSONObject
JSONArray linkJSONArray = responseJSONObject.getJSONArray("Link");
```

Comment: Unless i'm missing something, Link is an array?

Comment: Hmm, I did try this. I tried again I get the same error but - org.json.JSONEXCEPTION: No Value for Response instead.

Comment: @user3882091 for you particular value of `jsonResult` (assuming it is correctly logged) and this particular code given by prosper, there is not reason it shouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The "Link" is a JSONArray instead of JSONObject.
So the code should be :

```
try {
    JSONObject response = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
    JSONArray test = response.optJSONArray("Link");
    if (test != null && test.length() > 0) {
        JSONObject test = test.optJSONObject(0);
        if( test != null) {
            String test1 = test.getString("SpeedLimit");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), test1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No speed limitation data found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

You also need to consider the situation that there are more than 1 JSONObject included in the Link JSONArray.